# Extract random sample from a unknown distribution (no generate stochastic random deviates)

Tags: r, random, distribution, sample

I have a vector of data. I need build the density / distribution function and from that, extract a random sample, i.e. I need obtain the result that give us a function similar to `rnorm()`, `rpois()`, `rbinom()`, etc, but with a distribution built from a vector of data. All in R. Thank you so much.

It has nothing to do with generate stochastic random deviates.

I know the function `sample()` do something similar, but not exactly. If I use `sample()` I obtain only elements from my original data, as a discrete distribution and I need as a continuous distribution.

Comment: If you're working from a finite sample of data, you'll need to do some extrapolation to get a density from it. This requires some assumptions- for example, you could perform kernel density estimation to it and try to draw from that distribution, or you could use a parametric method. Do you have a method in mind? (If not, this question may be better on stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: (As [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087312/generate-a-random-number-from-a-density-object-or-more-broadly-from-a-set-of-nu) notes, if you use kernel density estimation and draw from it, that is the exact same as drawing a random element with `sample` and then adding random noise according to the kernel function)